# Why I got this error: POST https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions 400?

Tags: json, api, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Here is my code:

```
export async function getStructuredMessage(messageText) {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            messages: [{ role: 'system', content: messageText }],
        }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    return data.choices[0].message.content;
}
```

Why I got this error: POST https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions 400?

here I use the function

```
async function fetchStructuredMessage() {
    const response = await getStructuredMessage(message.text);
    setStructuredMessage(response);
}
```

Comment: 400 is a broad error that basically means the server didn't like the data you sent.  Maybe you sent the wrong data, or it was in the wrong format, or there was too much data, or too little, or the headers were wrong... lots of possibilities.

Comment: Was there a body in the response that had an explanation?

Comment: If I had to guess, it was that the model/deployment name was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Stephan Cleary is correct, you need supply the requried model.
You can find the requriements [here](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create).

So you should be able to change your body:

```
JSON.stringify({
            model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
            messages: [{ role: 'system', content: messageText }],
        })
```

Although I would not use the role 'system', but 'user' for a single message.  'system' is meant more for system messages / instructions to the model.